# Database project generate deployment script without any database creation

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, msbuild, database-deployment

This may be a stupid question or it might be that I am just not googling with the right strings.  I am trying to have my database project generate a deployment script that does not contain any create database statements.

Basically we are looking to generate a script that would be perfect to run after the person deploying has already created the database.

I didn't see any options for it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833291.aspx). Something like the CommentOutSetVarDeclarations but for the database creation parts of the scripts would be awesome.

Any thoughts are appreciated.